# google maps in UIWebView passing data from core

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, google-maps

I want to use to UIWebView to display google maps mobile website for my app. However; I need the current user location to be passed into the webview so that it may show a route. What steps must I take in order to not only pass the current location to the google maps url but also pass what I want it to route(for example, Costco)?

Second, my app is going to be a paid app and I was wondering if it is even possible to use google maps due to this? The app does not only have gps but other sections as well that I created myself.

Thank you so much

Comment: the way to do it is to use the iOS MapKit or other frameworks (like routeme with openstreetmap). It behaves better than maps in an webview (feel the difference between browser-maps and maps-app). AT the end route- and position-display is easy in MapKit and routeme

Comment: Thank you thomas. Can you please expand on "AT the end route"? Also if  I use routeme, can I still charge for my app? From what I see, this is  open source?

Comment: It is possible to draw polyines (which represents a route) on-top or within any map-illustration. The easiest way is to use the mapkit (most people use that). Then take a look at that link: http://spitzkoff.com/craig/?p=65 if you dont want to use mapkit then you can use a framework named "route-me" which is open-source and it is configurable to use either open-street-map or google or sth. else. how to draw a polyline within route-me: http://groups.google.com/group/route-me-map/browse_thread/thread/3253535717d4cabc?pli=1

Comment: Oh okay makes sense. The problem is though I do not want to draw the routes for it would take months and months. I want to be able get the users location and then for example enter "grocery stores" and then all the grocery stores near the user are shown. The user then selects the closest and he is given directions to the location. Pretty much its the google maps app without actually using the app. Is this possible or am I way off?

Comment: Thanks for your help btw, really appreciate it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you dont want to show google-maps in an `UIWebView`. You should use either the [MapKit-Framework](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MapKit_Framework_Reference/_index.html) or any other maps-framework like for instance [route-me](https://github.com/route-me/route-me/wiki/_pages).

In both framework it is possible to draw polylines (links: [MapKit](http://spitzkoff.com/craig/?p=65), [route-me](http://groups.google.com/group/route-me-map/browse_thread/thread/3253535717d4cabc?pli=1)) (which represents a route) and any other stuff like pins and a bubble with a circle around it which indicates the current location (links: [MapKit](http://www.google.com/search?q=cmapkit+current+location+cicrlce#q=mapkit+current+location+circle+site%3astackoverflow.com&fp=1), route-me (should be somewhere in the sample-programs)).